# Is there a way to get FC Barcelona's third kit/alternative in FIFA 14 Ultimate Team?

Tags: fifa-14

Do you have to get it in packs or is it rare in the transfer market? I am not talking about the classic kit.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you just need to search it in the "Club Items" tab in the transfer market, by selecting the country and league. Just out of interest, what colour is the third kit for Barcelona?